# Solidity inserting data that maps addresses to arrays of bytes32 error

Tags: addresses, mapping, bytes32

My contract is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract try {
    mapping (address=>bytes32[10]) Map;

    function try(){}

    function fill_map(bytes32[10] _attributes) public  {
            Map[msg.sender].push(_attributes);
    }

    function get_map(address id) view public returns (bytes32[10]){
      return Map[id];
    }

}
```

The error I get is:

```
Member “push” not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in bytes32[10] storage reference Map[msg.sender].push(_attributes)
```

I also tried inserting the data with a loop as follows:

```
    for(uint i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        Map[msg.sender].push(_attributes[i]);
    }
```

Also results in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the data directly

```
function fill_map(bytes32[10] _attributes) public  {
        Map[msg.sender] = _attributes;
}
```

Also `try` is a reserved keyword and the compilation will fail. You have to use another name for your contract.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to insert data in a **mapping (key => value) Map** is

```
Map[key] = value
```

In your case it is `Map[msg.sender] = _attributes`

`push()` function inserts data into array but not into map.